# How do I insert user inputs from asp.net textbox controls into SQL Server Database table?

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I'm in ASP.NET and coding in VB.
My SQL Server DB table name TempPurchases has 3 columns:
 - ItemNumber (nvarchar(10),null)
 - RDC (nvarchar(2),null)
 - PurchaseQTY (int,null)

The user inputs to go into the table are: ItemNumberTxtBox, DropDownList1, QuantityTxtBox
This is my code:

```
Protected Sub AddButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AddButton.Click
   Dim CON As New SqlConnection("server=blahblah.com;database=databasename;User ID=fffffff;Password=*******;")
   Dim SQL As String = "INSERT INTO TempPurchases (ItemNumber, RDC, PurchaseQTY) VALUES (@ItemNumber, @RDC, @PurchaseQTY) "
   Dim CMD As New SqlCommand(SQL, CON)

   CMD.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@ItemNumber", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 10))
   CMD.Parameters("@ItemNumber").Value = ItemNumberTxtBox.Text

   CMD.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@RDC", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 2))
   CMD.Parameters("@RDC").Value = dropdownlist1.SelectedValue

   CMD.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@PurchaseQTY", SqlDbType.Int))
   CMD.Parameters("@PurchaseQTY").Value = QuantityTxtBox.Text

   CON.Open()
   CMD.ExecuteNonQuery()
   CON.Close()
End Sub
```

What am I doing wrong?  I'm not getting an error message but nothing is getting entered into the Database table.

Comment: Have you tried profiling the DB while running your code?

Comment: Is a row created with `NULL`s or nothing at all?

Comment: How about setting a breakpoint and stepping through your code.

Comment: Have you put break points in your code to verify that it actually executes the `ExecuteNonQuery()` call? Also, have you tried using `SQL Profiler` (like ElGavilan suggested)?

Comment: have you tried doing   CMD.Parameters("@PurchaseQTY").Value = Convert.ToInt32(QuantityTxtBox.Text)

Comment: Started following a tutorial on debugging with breakpoints and the nonquery was never executing.  It works now! Thanks for the help.